# setting of pageload timeout for clojure webdriver

Tags: selenium, clojure, webdriver

I am using clj webdriver, it throws the exception after waiting 1800 seconds. That's too long for me, how to set it to something like 120 seconds? I tried to use     implicit-wait, but it doesn't work

```
 org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page load.
Command duration or timeout: 1800.01 seconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: 'unknown', time: '2015-07-30 11:02:44'
System info: host: 'SomeHost', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=31.0, platform=LINUX, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 7def8969-2487-4e63-b6d2-5981e3defff4
```

update:
I used the following to get the firefox using clojure

```
 (require '[clj-webdriver.core :as cw])
(require '[clj-webdriver.firefox :as ff])
(defn get-checking-firefox [x]
  (let [directory (str "test" x)
        profile (doto (ff/new-profile (str "/home/oracle/.mozilla/firefox/" directory)))
        driver (cw/new-driver {:browser :firefox :profile profile})]
    (implicit-wait driver 120)
    (.. driver manage timeouts (pageLoadTimeout 30 TimeUnit/SECONDS))
    driver))
```

update:
when use

```
(.. driver manage timeouts (pageLoadTimeout 30 TimeUnit/SECONDS))
```

It throws the error of

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: manage for class clj_webdriver.driver.Driver
at clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField(Reflector.java:271)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeNoArgInstanceMember(Reflector.java:315)
at automate.core$get_firefox.invoke(core.clj:65)
```

If I println the method/field of the webdriver instance,there is no manage field or method:

```
automate.core=> (type a)
clj_webdriver.driver.Driver
automate.core=> (def b (reflect a)
           #_=> )
#'automate.core/b
automate.core=> (def c (:members b))
#'automate.core/c
automate.core=> (map println (map (fn[x] [(class x) (:name x)]) c))
[clojure.reflect.Method count]
[clojure.reflect.Method assoc]
[clojure.reflect.Method getLookupThunk]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__3]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__19]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__4]
[clojure.reflect.Method hashCode]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__23]
[clojure.reflect.Method keySet]
[clojure.reflect.Method entryAt]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__7]
[clojure.reflect.Method valAt]
[clojure.reflect.Method seq]
[clojure.reflect.Method empty]
[clojure.reflect.Method get]
[clojure.reflect.Constructor clj_webdriver.driver.Driver]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__2]
[clojure.reflect.Method containsValue]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__26]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__28]
[clojure.reflect.Method values]
[clojure.reflect.Method meta]
[clojure.reflect.Method put]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__29]
[clojure.reflect.Method isEmpty]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__15]
[clojure.reflect.Method without]
[clojure.reflect.Field cache_spec]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__10]
[clojure.reflect.Method size]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__12]
[clojure.reflect.Method assoc]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__13]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__8]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__22]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__30]
[clojure.reflect.Field __extmap]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__11]
[clojure.reflect.Method iterator]
[clojure.reflect.Method equals]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__18]
[clojure.reflect.Constructor clj_webdriver.driver.Driver]
[clojure.reflect.Method putAll]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__0]
[clojure.reflect.Method create]
[clojure.reflect.Field actions]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__27]
[clojure.reflect.Field webdriver]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__6]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__20]
[clojure.reflect.Method entrySet]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__14]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__24]
[clojure.reflect.Method cons]
[clojure.reflect.Method valAt]
[clojure.reflect.Method clear]
[clojure.reflect.Method withMeta]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__9]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__25]
[clojure.reflect.Method equiv]
[clojure.reflect.Method containsKey]
[clojure.reflect.Field __meta]
[clojure.reflect.Method getBasis]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__1]
[clojure.reflect.Method hasheq]
[clojure.reflect.Field capabilities]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__21]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__16]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__5]
[clojure.reflect.Field const__17]
[clojure.reflect.Method remove]
```

Comment: Please post the line where you use implicit wait. It should be something similar to the following Java example: 
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: what's your version of clj-webdriver?

Comment: it's 0.7.2   [clj-webdriver "0.7.2"]

Comment: Sorry about that, the `.manage` call should be on `(:webdriver driver)`, so `(.. (:webdriver driver) manage timeouts (pageLoadTimeout 30 TimeUnit/SECONDS))` should work. I updated it in the answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should set a 30 seconds page load timeout:

```
(.. (:webdriver driver) manage timeouts (pageLoadTimeout 30 TimeUnit/SECONDS))
```

For `TimeUnit/SECONDS` to work you need `(:import [java.util.concurrent TimeUnit])` in your ns form

Comment: I complains it can't find manage. I am using clj-webdriver.core

Comment: It should work... what's the exact code you are trying, and the exact error you get?